# Redshift: Numeric data overflow (result precision)

Tags: sql, casting, amazon-redshift, precision

Hi I have a Redshift DB and am trying to insert data from the table "scans" / column "net_rate" (data type numeric) into another table "visits_by_scan" / column "scan_cost" (data type numeric). The query I am using is the below:

```
insert into visits_by_scan (scan_cost)
select sum(cast(s.net_rate as decimal(30,4))) 
from scans s
```

When I try to run this query I get the following numeric overflow error message:

[image]

How to insert the data without any errors? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, have you tried `decimal(31, 4)` ?

Comment: Yeah, same issue unfortunately...

Comment: what's the value of sum(s.scan_cost) without casting?

Comment: @eshirvana The value is "725978152.0180".

Comment: @eshirvana It is numeric. They are both numeric: "scan_cost" and "net_rate".

Comment: @ERR have you defined precision for your numeric data type columns? because if not the default is 18 and now when you cast to precision 30 Redshift doesn't like it.

Comment: @eshirvana Yeah so I finally managed to check the DDL for the table "scans" and confirmed the datatype for the column "net_rate" had been defined as decimal(8,2), which is too small to accommodate for "725978152.0180". I have then asked them to change the datatype for that column to decimal (13,2) and the data loaded successfully now. Thank you for your help / tip.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to check the what is the type of the column you are going to insert
2. use the type in the value you insert.

According to my understanding, the error means that the type of value that you want to insert is different with the type of value in the column.

For example, you cannot inset 1.3333 into a column with only one-digit value like 1.3.